# Giving a width to the element not applied to the hidden element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is my snippet. If you click on the button that has the label "toggle the second `div`, then the `div` that has id "second" will be hidden/shown.

Now, the problem is, width of the `div`s that have class "overflow_x" inside the `div` that has id "second", is not given to the width of base on its parent container (`div` that has a class of "perent"). If you don't hide the `div` that has id "second" (remove the "thehide" class), you can see that its child `div` (`div` that has a class of "overflow_x") has been given a width equal to its parent container (`div` that has a class of "perent") but if you hide it by default, the child `div`s (`div` that has a class of "overflow_x") are not given the width equals to its parent container (`div` that has a class of "perent").

Any help, ideas, clues, recommendations, suggestions please?

PS: from my observation, it looks like its giving a percent width instead of pixels.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  $(".overflow_x table").hide();
  $(".overflow_x").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).closest(".perent").width() + 'px');
            $(this).css({ 'width' : $(this).closest(".perent").width() + 'px' });
            if($(this).find("table").length){
                $(this).find("table").show();

            }
        });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".thehide").hide();
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#second").toggle();

  });
});
```

```css
.overflow_x{overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;border: 1px solid red;}
.table{width: 100%;}
.table th, .table td{text-align: center;text-transform: uppercase;}
.table th:first-child{text-align: left !important;}
.extend{max-width:100%;max-height:100%;}
.clear{clear:both !important;float:none !important;}
.full_width{width: 100%;}
.center{margin-left: auto !important; margin-right: auto !important;}
.divider{height: 10px; clear: both; float: none; width: 100%;}
.display_table{display: table;}
#first{border: 1px solid red;padding:15px;}
#second{border: 1px solid blue;padding:15px;}
.thehide{display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="btn btn-success" id="btn1">TOGGLE THE SECOND DIV</button>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="full_width extend clear" id="first">

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-6 perent">
        <div class="overflow_x">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Head 1</th>
                  <th>Head 2</th>
                  <th>Head 3</th>
                  <th>Head 4</th>
                  <th>Head 5</th>
                  <th>Head 6</th>
                  <th>Head 7</th>
                  <th>Head 8</th>
                  <th>Head 9</th>
                  <th>Head 10</th>
                  <th>Head 11</th>
                  <th>Head 12</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>Head 1</td>
                  <td>Head 2</td>
                  <td>Head 3</td>
                  <td>Head 4</td>
                  <td>Head 5</td>
                  <td>Head 6</td>
                  <td>Head 7</td>
                  <td>Head 8</td>
                  <td>Head 9</td>
                  <td>Head 10</td>
                  <td>Head 11</td>
                  <td>Head 12</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 perent">
        <div class="overflow_x">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Head 1</th>
                  <th>Head 2</th>
                  <th>Head 3</th>
                  <th>Head 4</th>
                  <th>Head 5</th>
                  <th>Head 6</th>
                  <th>Head 7</th>
                  <th>Head 8</th>
                  <th>Head 9</th>
                  <th>Head 10</th>
                  <th>Head 11</th>
                  <th>Head 12</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>Head 1</td>
                  <td>Head 2</td>
                  <td>Head 3</td>
                  <td>Head 4</td>
                  <td>Head 5</td>
                  <td>Head 6</td>
                  <td>Head 7</td>
                  <td>Head 8</td>
                  <td>Head 9</td>
                  <td>Head 10</td>
                  <td>Head 11</td>
                  <td>Head 12</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  </div>

  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="full_width extend clear thehide" id="second">

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-6 perent">
        <div class="overflow_x">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Head 1</th>
                  <th>Head 2</th>
                  <th>Head 3</th>
                  <th>Head 4</th>
                  <th>Head 5</th>
                  <th>Head 6</th>
                  <th>Head 7</th>
                  <th>Head 8</th>
                  <th>Head 9</th>
                  <th>Head 10</th>
                  <th>Head 11</th>
                  <th>Head 12</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>Head 1</td>
                  <td>Head 2</td>
                  <td>Head 3</td>
                  <td>Head 4</td>
                  <td>Head 5</td>
                  <td>Head 6</td>
                  <td>Head 7</td>
                  <td>Head 8</td>
                  <td>Head 9</td>
                  <td>Head 10</td>
                  <td>Head 11</td>
                  <td>Head 12</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 perent">
        <div class="overflow_x">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Head 1</th>
                  <th>Head 2</th>
                  <th>Head 3</th>
                  <th>Head 4</th>
                  <th>Head 5</th>
                  <th>Head 6</th>
                  <th>Head 7</th>
                  <th>Head 8</th>
                  <th>Head 9</th>
                  <th>Head 10</th>
                  <th>Head 11</th>
                  <th>Head 12</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>Head 1</td>
                  <td>Head 2</td>
                  <td>Head 3</td>
                  <td>Head 4</td>
                  <td>Head 5</td>
                  <td>Head 6</td>
                  <td>Head 7</td>
                  <td>Head 8</td>
                  <td>Head 9</td>
                  <td>Head 10</td>
                  <td>Head 11</td>
                  <td>Head 12</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  </div>
```